# Making regex match optional

Tags: regex

I am new to regex and I need your help.
I need to parse the following text:

```
2DB337649|required-match|groupName1=value1^groupName2=value2^junk1=junkval^junk2=junkval^groupName3=value3^junk3=junkval^groupName4=value4^`
```

I need to get the values out of it while ignoring the junk.
I have used the following regex:

```
(?=.*required-match).+groupName1=(?<group1>.*?)\^groupName2=(?<group2>[^^]+).+groupName3=(?<group3>[^^]+).+groupName4=(?<group4>.*?)\^
```

I works fine but the problem is that sometimes value groupName3 is missing and I get no matches.

Is there a way to get the groupName3 if it is found and if not just go further to groupName4?

[Link to example](https://regex101.com/r/PNFjdT/1/)

Thank you.

Comment: Try making the part for groupName optional using an optional non capturing group `(?=.*required-match).+groupName1=(?<group1>.*?)\^groupName2=(?<group2>[^^]+)(?:.+groupName3=(?<group3>[^^]+))?.+groupName4=(?<group4>.*?)\^` See https://regex101.com/r/kYCXSY/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part with `groupName3` can be in an optional non capturing group and you could make the `.+` non greedy using `.*?`

```
(?:.+?groupName3=(?<group3>[^^]+))?
```

The pattern might look like

```
(?=.*required-match).+?groupName1=(?<group1>.*?)\^groupName2=(?<group2>[^^]+)(?:.+?groupName3=(?<group3>[^^]+))?.+?groupName4=(?<group4>.*?)\^
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hbcm86/1)